# IIS6 cdo.message cannot send emails access denied error

Tags: email, iis-6, smtp, asp-classic

Got some very basic email code on a iis 6 server to send a test email. Relay is enabled on exchange server for this server, the iis user has write permissions to the directories for mailroot and all its subfolders, and yet we still get this blasted error still.

> CDO.Message.1 error 
>   '80070005' Access
>   is denied. /email.asp, line 42

I don't see any files in the pickup folder, there are files in the queue folder however. Any ideas what else I should look at?

The code on Line 42 is  myMail.Send

Comment: What is the code on line 42?

Comment: It is  myMail.Send

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem, it was permissions to the SMTP service. The IIS user nor did system have access to that. We added that and it is working now.

Comment: Good deal, thanks for the follow-up!

Answer (score 1):

That indicates that your server is not allowing CDO to send messages through it.  The most frequent cause of this is an authentication issue.  If your Exchange server requires authentication check the app code that sets up the authentication.  Ensure that 1) it's using authentication and 2) the username and pwd are in fact correct.

Comment: Not sure if the exchange server is requiring authentication, which may be the case. If it is, then that definitely needs to be added to the code as it does not have it.